# Firestore & React: Update the Same State in Multiple Firestore onSnapshot Listeners

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect, use-state

We are building a chat app using Firestore and React.
Users should be able to up/down-vote each other's messages.
We have two Firestore collections:

- `messages`: contains the message, sender, dateTime, totalVotes, ....
- `votes`: contains the userVote, voter, messageId, dateTime, ....

Our React state `messages` is an array including all the messages to show in the UI. Each of its elements is an object with the content of the `message`, `sender`, `dateTime`, and `totalVotes`, in addition to `userVote`, i.e., the vote cast by the authenticated user for this message.

```
const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([
  {
    message,
    sender,
    dateTime,
    totalVotes,
    userVote
  },
  ...
]);
```

We have two `firestore.onSnapshot`s that listen to all the changes in `messages` and `votes` collections. This way, as soon as a message is added/updated or the user cast or change their vote for a message, the corresponding change is show in the UI.

We defined these listeners in a `useEffect` with no dependencies. Every time something changes in `messages` or `votes`, inside `firestore.onSnapshot` we call `setMessages` and get its previous value to update accordingly. However, when a user votes for a message, because simultaneously:

- The message document changes it totalVotes
- The vote document changes its values

both `firestore.onSnapshot`s get fired, but only one of the two `setMessages` calls works fine. The other one messes up.

How should we solve this issue?

Comment: This question is not about creating a simple React + Firebase Chat app. Please carefully read the question.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and share the code you're using to have a [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)